# ASP.Net check if radiobuttons are checked doesn't work in backend

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button

This is my frontend code

```
<table width="50%">
    <tr>
       <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text=" NL" GroupName="lang"/></td>
       <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text=" FR" GroupName="lang"/></td>
       <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text=" DE" GroupName="lang"/></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

This is my backend (.vb) code

```
If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
   .LanguageId = 1
ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
   .LanguageId = 2
ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
   .LanguageId = 3
Else
   .LanguageId = 4

End If
```

Somehow it always gives languageId 4, so the if and elseif are not true (which is not the case there's definitely always one checked).

Any ideas what can be the problem?

Comment: It works just fine when I tried it. Are you resetting the checked values somewhere on postback?

Comment: No. And normally the else wouldn't be necessary (I Just put it there to test is). So if I put the else in comments it gives an error that says "LanguageId is required". Though a radiobutton is checked.

Comment: Where and when are you checking the values?

Comment: It's in another file (it's a huge project which I'm jus jumping in right now). It just does this:  If request.IFile.LanguageId = 0 Then
            Throw New OopsExceptions(Test.LibMain.TranslationsCrosCrea.fGetString("cros_langid_req"), "sValidateCreateIFileStep1", EOopsException.IFILE_ImportInitFailed)
        End If

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying it is a big project with more code, maybe you're manipulating two objects where you think they're one.

For debugging purposes, write all the values to the console. 
Console. WriteLine(radio button 1. Checked. To string)

The line has improper syntax but you should get the idea. Coding on a phone is impossible.

You should be able to understand what your code is doing this way and locate where the logic does not follow and ask a better question.

Comment: Couldn't find the problem... Fixed it with putting the value of the clicked RadioButton in a hidden field.